# ADAL 3.17.3 with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, adal

i can't figure out how to create a project with Xamarin that use ADAL for authentication.

Visual Studio 2017

ADAL 3.17.3

Xamarin Shared Project or .NET standard, for me is the same, i even haven't understand what is needed for ADAL to work.

Latest updates in place.

Anyone got a good link for a tutorial or just any suggestion?

Pls note, iv'e tried something like 4, 5 tutorials, no one work. With shared project on android it says that can't load some part of the dlls, on .NET standard, the project won't compile at all.

All tutorials i've found were posted at least one year ago, when the ADAL was not just relaeased but on the preview channel.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you have a look at this sample:
https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget

If you are using a PCL library that consumes ADAL.NET be sure to also reference ADAL.NET in your Xamarin.Android project to be sure that the right DLL is picked-as the NuGet package supports several platforms as explained [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/ADAL.NET-supports-multiple-application-architectures-and-multiple-platforms)